# unit test - mockito testing to check if another method is invoked

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

Summary: I am trying to test if a method is invoked once I call one method.

What this class does is, displays information of wrong spelled words and provides u with buttons to 'ignore' or 'ignore all' or 'add to dictionary', etc.

Over here 'ignore' is a JButton declared above.

I am trying to write one test for this method ->

```
 public class SpellCheckerDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

 ...
 ..

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ev ) {
    Object source = ev.getSource();
    if( source == ignore ) {
        searchNext();

    }
  }
 ...
}
```

Here is what it is invoking, I am testing to see if this method is being invoked or not.

```
...

//inside same class
public boolean searchNext() {
    String wordStr;
    while( true ) {
        wordStr = tok.nextInvalidWord();
        if( wordStr == null ) {
            dispose();
            String title = SpellChecker.getApplicationName();
            if(title == null){
                title = this.getTitle();
            }
            SpellChecker.getMessageHandler().handleInformation( getParent(), title, Utils.getResource( "msgFinish" ) );
            return false;
        }
        if( ignoreWords.contains( wordStr ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        String changeTo = changeWords.get( wordStr );
        if( changeTo != null ) {
            replaceWord( wordStr, changeTo );
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    word.setText( wordStr );
    notFound.setText( wordStr );

    List<Suggestion> list = dictionary.searchSuggestions( wordStr );

    boolean needCapitalization = tok.isFirstWordInSentence() && Utils.isFirstCapitalized( wordStr );

    Vector<String> suggestionsVector = new Vector<String>();
    for( int i = 0; i < list.size() && i < options.getSuggestionsLimitDialog(); i++ ) {
        Suggestion sugestion = list.get( i );
        String newWord = sugestion.getWord();
        if( needCapitalization ) {
            newWord = Utils.getCapitalized( newWord );
        }
        if( i == 0 )
            word.setText( newWord );
        suggestionsVector.add( newWord );
    }
    suggestionsList.setListData( suggestionsVector );

    addToDic.setEnabled( true );
    return true;
}
```

What I have tried until now, tried using Mockito and calling the verify method, but this code snippet seems to not working or have lots of dependencies that I am struggling to get around.

Inside my TestClass, I have this - >

```
    Dialog fr = Mockito.mock(Dialog.class);
    SpellCheckerDialog sD = new SpellCheckerDialog(fr);
    sD.searchNext();

    Mockito.verify(sD, Mockito.times(1)).thenReturn(searchNext());
```

I don't know if I should be making a stub for my (ActionEvent ev) or ...

Comment: What's the name of the class containing `actionPerformed`, and the name of the class containing `searchNext`? Are they the same class? Is SpellCheckerDialog a subclass of Dialog, or does it contain and operate on a Dialog? (Sorry for the barrage of questions, but it'll help to understand and explain.)

Comment: I have edited to reflect ur questions. Hope it answers them. :)

Comment: It looks like you may want a Mockito "spy", which will enable you to run your `actionPerformed` method, then verify your `searchNext` method.

Answer (score 1):

Verifications must be done on the mocks created by Mockito, because the framework can't possibly know what happens with objects that it does not manage. This being said, your `searchNext()` method is part of your **class under test** so you probably want to [spy on it](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) just like in the example below:

```
public class SpyTest {

    class MyClass {

        public void callDoSomething(){
            doSomething();
        }

        public void doSomething(){
            // whatever
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSpyAndVerifyMethodCall(){
         MyClass objectUnderTest = new MyClass();
         MyClass spy = Mockito.spy(objectUnderTest);

        spy.callDoSomething();

        Mockito.verify(spy, Mockito.times(1)).doSomething();
    }
}
```

My advice is to go through the Mockito documentation and examples from the [link above](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13), as they're pretty straight-forward and should give you a good starting point.

---

**EDIT** as per your comment:

```
public class SpyTest {
    class MyClass {
        private JButton myButtton;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getSource() == myButtton) {
                searchNext();
            }
        }

        public void searchNext(){
            // whatever
        }
    }

    @Mock // define a mock for the button to "hack" the source check
    private JButton mockButton;

    @InjectMocks // inject the mock in our object under test
    private MyClass objectUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void shouldSpyAndVerifyMethodCall(){
        // spy on our object so we can query various interactions
        MyClass spy = spy(objectUnderTest);

        // event mock
        ActionEvent mockEvent = mock(ActionEvent.class);

        // "hack" the source check
        when(mockEvent.getSource()).thenReturn(mockButton);

        // call main logic
        spy.actionPerformed(mockEvent);


        // verify interactions
        verify(spy).searchNext();  // times(1) not needed because it's the implicit/default setting, see David's comment
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever write `Mockito.times(1)` - it is the default verification mode, so explicitly writing it is just unnecessary clutter in your test.  The last line above should just be written `Mockito.verify(spy).doSomething();`

Comment: You basically quoted the 'spy' thingy from Mockito documentation, which is good. I was aware of spy, but I don't know how to make a mock of ActionEvent to fit my situation here. Any code sample within the scope of my problem here maybe?

Comment: @DavidWallace I sometimes use if for didactic purposes, but you are correct, thanks for pointing it out, I'll have the second example do just that

Comment: @user3547204 You're right, I did quote spy from the docs and suggested you go over them, because you seemed to be missing the essentials in your test sample. If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, you'll have to make a mix of mocks and spies like in the second example